# How to add/use kiwiviewer in ios app to view .ply file (3d model) or any other way

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d

I am building an ios app on xcode that at some point i have to display a 3d model to the user , I have read and search until i found something called kiwiviewer , the 3d model is (.ply) files so i want a help how to add kiwiviewer to xcode or  use it inside the app, or if there is other way to view the 3d models in iphone app .

I searched and watched a youtube video that have no sound and did not get the way , please help.

I am using ios 5.1 .
[image: kiwiviewer]

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kiwi viewer does not support the PLY files so the above answer is not right you can use a VTP files in order to view it in 3D via kiwi viewer so try to convert your file to VTP and use the same function mentioned above.

```
  std::string dataset = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skull" ofType:@"vtp"] UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in KiwiSimple (lite version of KiwiViewer) to load PLY files:

```
-(void) initializeKiwiApp
{
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

  std::string dataset = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"skull" ofType:@"ply"] UTF8String];

  self->mKiwiApp = vesKiwiViewerApp::Ptr(new vesKiwiViewerApp);
  self->mKiwiApp->initGL();
  [self resizeView];
  self->mKiwiApp->loadDataset(dataset);
  self->mKiwiApp->resetView();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will need to add the data file to the project (via add files like the teapot.vtp in the sample). Hope this helps.

Comment: @flashdisk what version of kiwi viewer / ves you are using? The current version (from master) can load ply files. Let me know if this is not what you experience.

Comment: ply file did not work .. but vtp file did works.. do you know how to get ply file to work ..?

Comment: what version of VES you are using? Can you try building next? > git fetch origin > git checkout next > git reset --hard origin/next